# ThinkingSphinx, problem with setting `time` attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Unfortunatelly Thinking Sphinx can't simply convert `time` field to attribute

```
class Place << ActiveRecord::Base
#... relations

define_index
  #...
  has breakfast_start, :as => breakfast_start
end
```

`rake ts:rebuild`:

```
rake aborted!

Cannot automatically map attribute breakfast_start in Place to an
equivalent Sphinx type (integer, float, boolean, datetime, string as ordinal).
You could try to explicitly convert the column's value in your define_index
block:
  has "CAST(column AS INT)", :type => :integer, :as => :column

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Changing to `has "CAST(column AS INT)", :type => :integer, :as => :column` syntax also don't fix that:

```
ERROR: index 'place_core': sql_range_query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) AS `breakfast_start` FROM `places`
```

Anyone knows how to fix that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's a bad example from TS - try `UNSIGNED INT` instead of `INT`.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extra thought. It pays to check your database has the column it is trying to index as well. It can throw the same error if the column doesn't exist which makes the error message slightly un imformative.

Running rake db:migrate fixed all of this as I just loaded a prod copy into development for testing and none of the thinking sphinx delta columns were in this database copy.

Hope this helps anyone else who finds a similar problem.